# Check whether a user used facebook sdk to login into app previously

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently I have a code where I have a facebook login button in my login page. And right now I'm trying to make a check first whether a user already logged in into my app using facebook when the facebook login button is clicked. I read the facebook documentation  [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus)  on how to do it but I have no idea where to apply this in my code.

`loginbutton`

```
LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","public_profile"));
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d("LoginResult : ", loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            try{

                                // Application code
                                String email = object.getString("email");
                                String firstName = object.getString("first_name");
                                String lastName = object.getString("last_name");

                                ArrayList<String> publicProfile = new ArrayList<String>();

                                publicProfile.add(email);
                                publicProfile.add(firstName);
                                publicProfile.add(lastName);

                                new RegisterGetList(LoginActivity.this,mProgressView,LoginActivity.this, publicProfile).execute();

                            }
                            catch (JSONException e1){
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

We will get Facebook user account id,So from the backend you have to check whether that userId is already registered or not.Then you can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the email in shared preferences and you can check if shared preferences is null or not.

```
SharedPreferences sp=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String email=sp.getString("email",null);
if(email==null)
 {
//first log in
//store the email in shared prefernces 
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
  editor.putString("email",value);
  editor.apply();
 }    
else
{
 //already logged in 
}
```

clear the sp when user wil logout.

Answer (score 0):

Check this in your onCreate that user is logged in or not.

```
  if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
      getUserDetails();
    } else{
      loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile",   "email"));
    }
```

and getting user details using :

```
 private void getUserDetails() {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject object,
                        GraphResponse response) {

                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Response >>: " + object.toString());

                        String userID = object.getString("id");
                        String strName = object.getString("name").toString();
                        String strgander = object.getString("gender").toString();
                        String strEmail = object.getString("email").toString();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,link,gender,age_range,cover,picture,location");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

set permission in Login button's onClick.

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
        }
    });
```

set callback to Login button using

```
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

And, finally just call "getUserDetails()" inside onSuccess callback of your login button.